# Mobile Header is not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, header

I have created a mobile header only for mobile devices. My problem now is, if you click on *Menü*, the menu shows up but you cannot hide the menu again by clicking on *Schliessen*. Also the function `closeExtendMenuMobile()` got set with an onclick event.

Also, if you call the function `closeExtendMenuMobile()` in the console, the menu colapses again. How is that?

Why is the event not clickable and how can I fix that?

Here ist the website I am talking about: https://classymagazin.de/home/
You have to load the website as a 'mobile device'. Means, below 920px!

Comment: `mobile header` makes me wonder what you're talking about.  I'd describe this as an `HTML page heading link` or something like that.  Also, it would be good if you could include source code for the menu link and the button which is calling your close function.

Comment: Please include all the relevant code in your question, we never want to rely on outside webpages (because they can and will change). As the question stand it will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div#headerHeadingMobile {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The element with the Id of `extendMenuMobile` is overlapping the link so you cannot tap it.

Maybe try giving `extendMenuMobile` a position of absolute and a top to push it down so that the link is not covered.

OR

Set #extendMenuMobile and .vc_custom_1509619992888  to position relative and give them appropriate z-index's.

I found this using firefox's "Responsive Design Mode" set to a mobile size and the firefox built in "Inspector" both are under the "Developer" section.